# how do i generate report when i select the starting and ending date using php

Tags: php, html

I am working on employee attendance system and the attendance is working perfectly but the issue now is how do I  generate the attendance report when I select the employee name and the starting and ending date? am done with the html code all i need now is the php code that would work with my present html code.please i would appreciate your help thanks in advance.
below is the html code.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Select Employee Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee Full Name" required>
            <option value="">Select Employee Name</option>
            <?php
                $get = mysql_query("SELECT employee_name FROM employee");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
            ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo($row['employee_name'])?>" >
                    <?php echo($row['employee_name']) ?>
                </option>
            <?php
                }               
            ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Start Date</label>       
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="Start_date" class="input-group date form-control" date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="0000-00-00" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">End Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="end_date" class="input-group date form-control" date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="0000-00-00" required>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Generate Report">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th> Employee Id</th>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Date In</th>
                        <th>Time In</th>
                        <th>Late</th>
                        <th>Tools</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your exact difficulty?

Comment: @yakobom  i want the report to show on a table after when i have selected the employee name, start date& end date

Answer (score 0):

Change your query accordingly, like:

```
"SELECT employee_name FROM employee WHERE '".$date."' BETWEEN (start_date, end_date);"
```

Or you can also use `>=` and `<=` to compare the dates

Comment: i need it to be showing in the table i created below the generate report button

Answer (score 0):

Just add a print button and give an ID to it. Include JS code:

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/9DbEP/4/